# MPPT charge controller with resistance/inductive load and no battery?

Tags: power, dc, mppt

The most popular application of solar MPPT is for battery charging. There is a big market for these MPPT charge controllers (of varying quality and power specs to be sure) and they are available for much less than $100. There are also ICs for a few dollars. On the other hand, MPPT controllers for a resistive load (water heater) are much less common. The cheapest I can find commercially available today is [$300](http://techluck.com/index.php#buy). And for an inductive load (water pump or other motor) they are called Linear Current Boosters and the cheapest I can find is $150.

My question is: can a resistor (heating element) or inductor (DC motor) be connected as the load to an MPPT charge controller and would this work to maximize power to such a load? I would set the battery float voltage above the maximum voltage of the PV supply and set a high output current limit. I'd also disconnect the controller when power is so low that it can't even power the controller.

Perhaps some controllers would be better suited to this than others-- what kinds of things could go wrong?

Comment: a charge controller expects to "see" a battery at its output ... how it would behave without a battery is dependent on its design

Comment: Technically yes, but most are me the for a battery load. I’ve seen solar MPPTs for pumps, so they do exist commercially.